# confused about setting header and footer information?

Tags: header-footer, footer, pagestyle

I have gone through the reference manual and am still a little confused about how the `\markright`, `\markboth`, `\rightmark` commands, etc. With  working example, I would perhaps be able to figure it out and tweak things on my own. I want to achieve the following style:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| SECTION HEADER            Microprocessor Lab  | (header)
| --------------------------------------------- |
| 1 Section Header                              |
                     ...
                     ...
|                                               |
| My Name        Page Number   University Name  |  (footer)
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Based on my little understanding, this is all that I was able to come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\markright{\rightmark\hfill Microprocessor Lab\hfill}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

which obviously doesn't work. So any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package `fancyhdr`. The plain TeX/LaTeX commands are rather confusing (as you found out).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{Microprocessor Lab}
\fancyfoot[L]{My name}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{University Name}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

myheadings uses `\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}` for the header on odd pages. `\rightmark` is set using `\markright`, so `\markright{\rightmark}` doesn't do anything.  Also, myheadings uses `\let\sectionmark\@gobble` instead of anything useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfill Microprocessor Lab\hfill}%
\def\sectionmark#1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \thesection\quad
        \fi
        #1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```